# Retrieving JSON elements in Swift 3

Tags: json, swift

I have following JSON file

```
{
    "events": [
               {
               "date": "01/11/2017",
               "name": [
                        "Tulsi Vivah",
                        "Pradosh Vrat"
                        ],
               "photo": [
                         "photo_chaturthi",
                         "photo_ekadashi"
                         ]
               },
               {
               "date": "03/11/2017",
               "name": [
                        "Guru Nanak Jayanti"
                        ],
               "photo": [
                         "photo_chaturthi",
                         "photo_ekadashi"
                         ]
               }
               ]
}
```

I want to parse this and put the elements in the objectArray in the code below:

```
struct Objects {

        var sectionName : String!
        var sectionObjects : [String]!
        var sectionImages : [String]!
    }
    var objectArray = [Objects]()
```

I have written following code for reading the file:

```
if let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "EventsEnglish112017", withExtension: "json") {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: [])
```

My question is how do I typecast "json" to read the individual elements to fill the above `objectArray`.

Thanks!

Comment: There are multiple tools you could use, there is no need to do it by hand - though you can, if you want to. Take a look at [Object Mapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper)
 or [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) for example.

Comment: Don't declare your structs properties implicitly unwrapped optionals just to get around creating an initializer (which the compiler can do automatically for structs). From the code in your question, I see no reason for any of the properties to be implicitly unwrapped optionals at all...

Comment: Edited for swift 3 . Try it, it will definitely help you and inform me if still getting problem . Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

A JSON is a dictionary of type `[String:Any?]`
To parse it:

```
if let dictionary = json as? [String: Any?] {
    if let events = dictionary["events"] as? [[String: Any?]] {

    // events is an array of JSON objects, so it's an array of dictionaries
       for item in events
       {
          let date = item["date"] as? String // this is a String?
          let name = item["name"] as? [String]
          // same goes for 'photo'
        }
    }
}
```

Now that you have retrieved the data, you can use it to costruct your custom objects.
But it's better if you use some library that will make it for you, or use Swift4

Answer (score -1):

**To retrieve data from JSON file**

**(Swift 3)**

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("myJson", ofType: "json")
{
    if let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
    {
        if let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as? [String: Any]
        {
            if let eventsInfo = jsonResult["events"] as? [Any]
            {
                // Here you will get your data in Array format.
                // for e.g
                //   print(eventsInfo[0]["date"])
                // Just pass this eventsInfo (Array) into you Object model initializer and parse with the keys there.
            }
        }
     }
}
```

**(Swift 4)**

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myJson", ofType: "json") {
    do {
          let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
          let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves)
          if let jsonResult = jsonResult as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, let eventsInfo = jsonResult["events"] as? [Any] {
                    // Here you will get your data in Array format.
                    // for e.g
                    //   print(eventsInfo[0]["date"])
                    // Just pass this eventsInfo (Array) into you Object model initializer and parse with the keys there.
          }
      } catch {
           // handle error
      }
}
```

Comment: Why `path(forResource..` and `URL(fileURLWithPath` although there is `url(forResource..`? Why `.mutableLeaves` although the result is assigned  to an immutable constant? Why casting `eventsInfo` to dictionary although it's an array? Why `AnyObject` although the type is clearly value type (`Any`)? And your Swift 3 version is actually Swift 2 code.

Comment: @vadian Edited didn't saw his JSON properly